# Using Microsoft.Identity.Web to authenticate users for WebApp+API, and how to manage lifecycle

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to create a webapp that uses multi-tenant Azure AD for authentication & authorization. I'm trying to follow [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-sign-in-flow), using Microsoft.Identity.Web, and the pieces aren't clicking for me.

I've been able to successfully create a web app where users are able to login, get redirected back to my site, and get an `id_token` saved to their browser cookies so the web app is able to tell who they are. However, my web app *also* contains APIs itself, and it isn't clear to me how we're supposed to obtain an `access_token`, *as well as* manage the lifecycle by way of `refresh_tokens`, for calling APIs on the web app itself. In fact, refresh doesn't seem to be covered at all in the docs for Microsoft.Identity.Web.

Instead of the dedicated SDK, I've also tried using `AddCookie()`+`AddOpenIdConnect()` (the more generic solution). Using these middleware options I've successfully been able to obtain an `id_token`, `access_token`, *and* `refresh_token`. (Which seems to connect all the pieces of access, and refresh/lifecycle.) However, all of those tokens take up a fair amount of cookie space, and cause 431 Request Header Fields Too Large errors from Kestrel without customization.

It's clear that the intention is for access/refresh tokens to be stored server-side on some sort of in-memory or distributed cache. However, the documentation doesn't seem to outline how to deal with "web apps" that ALSO contain API controllers, and furthermore doesn't seem to outline how to deal with token refreshes in general.

Does anyone have any better in-code examples of how to configure a WebApp that authenticates users with Azure AD, and also properly handles refreshing the id/access tokens using the refresh_token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh tokens are automatically handled by MSAL.NET, which is used by Microsoft.Identity.Web.

We suggest you have a look at the following sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-3-AnyOrg but you would have the same clientID (and app) for your web app and web API.

Please also look at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Mixing-web-app-and-web-api-in-the-same-ASP.NET-core-app

Comment: RE: "Refresh tokens are automatically handled by MSAL.NET, which is used by Microsoft.Identity.Web."

When configured with `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp()`, I've noticed that the `id_token` saved in the browser cookies never seems to get updated. (The 'exp' field in the JWT is allowed to go past expiry.) Furthermore, `[Authorize]` attributes seem to continue to succeed even thought the id_token is expired. Is there something I'm missing?